# Cannot add a Scene with duplicate key: default

Tags: javascript, node.js, phaser-framework

I'm starting to learn the [Phaser 3](https://phaser.io/) framework, and I'm facing this big error and i have no idea why this is happening, the error is: Cannot add a Scene with duplicate key: default.

Both of my keys are completely different, what might be wrong here, I don't get it, I'm watching a youtube playlist tutorial and the guy have the same exact thing, and everything works fine for him, as it should.

My main difference is that I'm running all of this in a Node js Server, but I don't think that matters, I'm just serving the public folder which contains all of the game.

Here is some of my code

This is my my first scene

```
class BootLoader extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({
            Key: "BootLoader"
        });
    }

    preload() {
        alert("La escena del boot cargo");
    }
}

export default BootLoader;
```

This is the second scene

```
class ScenePlay extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super({
            Key: "ScenePlay"
        });
    }

    preload() {
        alert("La escena del scene cargo");
    }
}

export default ScenePlay;
```

This is my init file, that has the configuration of the game.

```
import ScenePlay from "./scenes/ScenePlay.js";
import BootLoader from "./bootloader.js";

const config = {
    width: 640,
    height: 400,
    parent: "container",
    physics: {
        default: "arcade"
    },
    scene: [
        ScenePlay,
        BootLoader
    ],
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

And here is the scripts running on my index.html file

```
<!-- Phaser libraries and my Game -->
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.16.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
<script src="./game/init.js" type="module"></script>
```

And here is my Node Js server file, but i dont think this is the problem

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier for others to help you if you share your source, e.g. in a github project.

Comment: You have `Key` rather than `key`.  In the [docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Scenes.Settings.html#.Config), the `config` object has a property `key` (lowercase).  Since this is omitted in your `config` it defaults, and the second one that you attempt to add will have a duplicate key.

Comment: @TrevorReid Oh Jesus, i knew it was soomething silly, thank you!!!!.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by defining a unique `key` within the constructor of each of your custom scene classes:

```js
class GameboardScene extends Phaser.Scene {

  constructor( ...args ) {
    super({ key: 'Gameboard', ...args })
  }

}
```

If you aren't passing a dictionary with a string `.key` property to the base Phaser Scene class, each of your scenes will evidently be assigned the fallback name "default" at runtime, causing the engine to blow up when it tries to ingest the second un-named scene.

I gleaned this by studying [this official demo](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/scenes/multiple-scenes-from-classes).

ETA: I'm using Phaser v3.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i just found the solution while sharing the same issue that originated this post.

the code

```
import ScenePlay from "./scenes/ScenePlay.js";
import BootLoader from "./bootloader.js";

const config = {
    width: 640,
    height: 400,
    parent: "container",
    physics: {
        default: "arcade"
    },
    scene: [
        ScenePlay,
        BootLoader
    ],
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

Is missing the Scene class initialization, and that's why Phaser does it with default values ending up in both scenes with the same "default" key.

Just add the following initialization lines between scene delaration and configuration:

```
var sceneToPlay = new ScenePlay();
var sceneToBoot = new BootLoader();
```

Then, modify your config to use the initialized class instances:

```
const config = {
        width: 640,
        height: 400,
        parent: "container",
        physics: {
            default: "arcade"
        },
        scene: [
            sceneToPlay,
            sceneToBoot
        ],
    }
```

This should fix it as it did for me.

best